# Using module packages in Pycharm

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I am super new to python and am trying to import a number of modules including numpy and matplotlib in Pycharm.

I have run

```
py -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ...
```

in the command prompt, which appears to have run successfully. However running

```
import numpy
```

in Pycharm gives

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

When I installed these modules through the terminal there was a line which read

> Stored in directory: C:\Users...

but using

```
from C:\Users\... import numpy
```

gives a syntax error.

If I try to go through the project interpreter in settings and install with pip that way I get

> AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

which apparently is how pip works now, and is why I went through the command prompt in the first place.
If I do

```
sys.path.append(C:\Users\...)
```

I get the same syntax error.
Could someone please explain getting these modules to work in the simplest way?
I find coding to come quite naturally, but just getting started can feel like climbing a mountain.

Comment: which version of pip are you using?

Comment: Could you add what ProjectInterpreter you have configured? You have probably created a new virtual environment when you created the project. When installing packages from the command line you are therefore not installing them in the same environment pycharm is using

Answer (score 0):

Please do it in a virtual environment

```
virtualenv --python=3.6 myvenv
source myvenv/bin/activate
pip install numpy
```

Then go to PyCharm's settings -> interpreter, and select the myvenv interpreter.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to configure the default interpreter:**

Run PyCharm, in the welcome window click **Configure > Preferences**:

[image]

In the Preferences window, under the **Project Interpreter** option select your python version, for example for python3.6:

[image: for python 3.x]

Click **Apply** and **OK**

Open your project, PyCharm should find the installed libraries.

Comment: Why the downvote? @Zero ask in an explicit way "..getting these modules to work", "..in the simplest way"